# resetting chart title on zoom button click in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a chart display from the following code and I'm trying to capture the text of the zoom button that is clicked (this particular chart has 4 different zoom button settings)to change the charts title. My latest effort shown below is also failing althought intellisense offered every option shown in the current attempt at setting buttonText.

```
var buttonText = 60;
$('#chartContainer').highcharts('StockChart', {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {

                    buttonText = event.target.rangeSelector.buttons.selected.text;
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 15,
                    text: '15D'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 30,
                    text: '30D'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 45,
                    text: '45D'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    count: 1,
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                selected: 3,
                inputEnabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: symbol + ' -- Last '+ buttonText +' Days'
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Price'
                },
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: 300,
                height: 100,
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],
            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: symbol,
                data: ohlc,
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach isn't going to work.  The click event only fires when the "background" of the chart is clicked and the buttons aren't in the background.

Instead, I'd hook the `redraw` event and then update the text on a `setTimeout` (since the redraw event fires before the draw).

```
       chart:{
            events: {
                redraw: function(event){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                       var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
                       var rS = chart.rangeSelector;
                       if (rS.selected != null){
                           var txt = rS.buttonOptions[rS.selected].text;
                           chart.setTitle({text: txt});
                       }
                    }, 200);
                },                    
            }
        },
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ugee/1/).

Comment: I had moved onto the redraw event but still couldn't get it working, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

there is a another simple way, you can override the RangeSelector.setSelected() method

```
Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.setSelected = function(selected) {
    this.selected = this.options.selected = selected;

    // get current Selected button's text
    var text = this.buttonOptions[selected].text;
    // then you can update chart's title
    chart.setTitle({
        text: text
    })
}
```